# draw Android UI programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

if I want to draw Android UI programmatically, which is the best layout to use....My app will catch a string from server and based upon this string it will draw UI elements like buttons
For example if it catches 1001 it means DRAW ,NOT DRAW,NOT DRAW,DRAw...

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific, I can't really understand what it is you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can have an XML layout with everything which could be drawn, and then you set the visibility of some of the components to `GONE`, depending on what you receive.

Comment: that could be very bad for exapmle if there are 10 elements on my UI and the string comes like this 10000000001 then only the first and last element will be drawn..and the space between them will destroy the look of my app

Comment: No. If you set the visibility of a component to `GONE` it will not take any space. It’s only if you set the visibility to `INVISIBLE` that it will.

Comment: This would not be dynamic. You could only have one button or x number of buttons that the xml has.

Comment: @Spidy Yes, of course, but given the example of the OP I supposed that this is the desired behaviour (disabling some components according to the input string).

Comment: @Guillaume - I guess the context is fuzzy. Your solution is absolutely correct in a different light.

Comment: @Spidy I agree that the context is fuzzy, I just tried to guess the most likely context.

Answer (score 1):

Getting a good layout programmatically can be a real pain for complicated layouts (which seems to be what you're going for).

What I would recommend is create a layout that contains all the elements you're going to make.  You can arrange them however you want.  Then, at runtime you can set their attributed to either View.GONE or View.INVISIBLE.

Else, the absolute easiest layout to use would be LinearLayout.  All you have to do is create and add views to it and they will stack on top each other.

The more difficult, but powerful layouts would be FrameLayout and RelativeLayout.  Those allow you to set the widgets wherever you want, but you have to adjust them based off gravity and LayoutParams which can get really complicated programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try a SurfaceView. It provides a blank drawing surface.

Barry

Answer (score 0):

You can add views (Buttons, TextViews, Layouts) programmatically by first getting the parent view, and then adding the new child view to it. Here's an example.

```
//This is inside an Activity class, any function you designate
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
Button myButton = new myButton(this);
myButton.setText("Click Me");
myLayout.addView(myButton);
```

**EDIT**

If you want to create the LinearLayou too, you can set it like this.

```
//This is inside an Activity class, any function you designate
LinearLayout myLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
Button myButton = new myButton(this);
myButton.setText("Click Me");
myLayout.addView(myButton);
setContentView(myLayout);
```

Comment: is it compulsory to get parent view?..Can we decalre linear layout object in class?

Comment: No. you do not need to get the parent view. you can create the layout and set it. see my edit above

Comment: i am doing exactly the same,when i click on button it starts a new activity that is developed programatically but my emulator is giving error...what could be the reason..the lisnter is perfectly well